# Access linux paths in windows git powershell

Tags: linux, windows, git, powershell

I am running a Windows Powershell provided through the [git for windows](http://gitforwindows.org/)  installation.  This shell provides many unix style commands (i.e. "ls", "mv", etc.).

My question is: How do I access Unix style paths from the powershell cmd line on Windows?

Consider this example:  the "ls" program is installed and works in the powershell.  The path is shown as "/usr/bin/ls" if I type "which ls" as the cmd prompt.  But if I try to change my current directory using "cd /usr/bin/", the shell complains that the path is not found.

[image]

I can't see any mounted volumes or anything like that using "mount" (perhaps in PowerShell it is a different command?).

I'm asking this question because I have other files that I need to get to which are listed under unix-style paths, and right now I can't get to anything.  I figure if I can get to /usr/bin, then I can figure out how to get where I really need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is not Unix. It may have a few familiar commands like "ls" and "ps", but that's where the similarity ends.

When you installed Git For Windows, you likely installed the Git Bash shell as well.  Run that instead to get a more Unix like atmosphere. (Re-install [Git For Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) if you didn't select this option on install).

But even with Git Bash, there's still no such folder as `/usr/bin`.  That folder doesn't exist on Windows.  If you want a Unix emulation on Windows that includes the traditional folder structure, use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  And you can run Git on that environment too and access an emulated `/usr/bin` folder.

Comment: understood that PS is not Unix - that's what I meant by "unix-style" paths.

Comment: @rothloup More accurately **Windows** is not **Unix**. Powershell does understand Unix **style** pathe (i.e. forward slashes rather than back slashes). What you are asking for is for Windows to understand and translate common Unix  **locations**. This just is not practical. usr/bin on a unix system is where most executeables are stored. Windows breaks up executeable locations and does not have one folder for them. Especially on 64bit machines.

Comment: @EBGreen I understand.  What is confusing here is that the powershell, in some way, DOES seem to understand the unix-style path since it provides commands and references files from those paths.

Comment: It does not. For instance type **Get-Alias ls** in powereshell. You will find that ls is simply an alias for Get-ChildItem. Powershell does not use ls.exe from the unix OS.